# Fill in Nulls with Row above

Tags: sql, mysql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am really struggling with producing some code create 'level1 question' & 'level2 question' columns.

The logic to populate the columns is:

- 'L1'  when level = 1 & type = group then question
- 'L2'  when level = 2 & type = group then question

But I can not find an efficient way of creating 'level1 question' & 'level2 question' like in the example.

| id | sort | type | question | level | answer | L1 | L2 | level1 question | level2 question |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **1** | **Group** | **Location** | **1** | **NULL** | **Location** | **NULL** | **Location** | **NULL** |
| 1 | 2 | Question | UK | 2 | Yes | NULL | NULL | Location | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | Question | EU | 2 | No | NULL | NULL | Location | NULL |
| *1* | *4* | *Group* | *Asia* | *2* | *Yes* | *NULL* | *ASIA* | *Location* | *ASIA* |
| 1 | 5 | Question | AUS | 3 | Yes | NULL | NULL | Location | ASIA |
| 1 | 6 | Question | NZ | 3 | No | NULL | NULL | Location | ASIA |
| **1** | **7** | **Group** | **Season** | **1** | **NULL** | **Season** | **NULL** | **Season** | **NULL** |
| 1 | 8 | Question | Summer | 2 | Yes | NULL | NULL | Season | NULL |
| **2** | **1** | **Group** | **City** | **1** | **NULL** | **City** | **NULL** | **City** | **NULL** |
| 2 | 2 | Question | London | 2 | Yes | NULL | NULL | City | NULL |
| *2* | *3* | *Group* | *Street* | *2* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *Street* | *City* | *Street* |
| 2 | 4 | Question | King ST | 3 | No | NULL | NULL | City | Street |

I have tried to use the following code but it is so slow. Just taken ~2 hours over 5 million rows.

```
'level1 question' = 
                (select top 1 L1 
                from table2 t2
                where L1 is not null
                and t1.Sort >= t2.Sort and t1.ID = t2.ID
                order by id , sort DESC)
, 'level2 question' = 
            (select top 1 L2 
            from table2 t2
            where L2 is not null AND (Level >2 OR Type = 'Group')
            and t1.Sort >= t2.Sort and t1.ID = t2.ID
            order by id , sort DESC)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: i think this is the 'last non-null' problem which was solved [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7379/last-non-null-value-set-of-sql-server-records/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your code suggests that you are  running SQL Server.

In the 2022 version, we can use `last_value()` with `ignore nulls` to efficiently retrieve the latest non-null of the conditional computation:

```
select t.*,
    last_value(case when level = 1 and type = 'Group' then question end) 
        ignore nulls
        over(partition by id order by sort) as level1_question,
    last_value(case when level = 2 and type = 'Group' then question end) 
        ignore nulls
        over(partition by id order by sort) as level2_question
from mytable t
```

---

In earlier versions (or in other databases that do not support `ignore nulls`), we can still use window functions (which *should* be more efficient that multiple subqueries on a large dataset), but that requires more work. The idea is to define groups of rows that contain one non-null value followed by 0 to N null values:

```
select t.*,
    max(question1) over(partition by id, grp1 order by sort) as level1_question,
    max(question2) over(partition by id, grp2 order by sort) as level2_question
from (
    select t.*,
        count(question1) over(partition by id order by sort) grp1,
        count(question2) over(partition by id order by sort) grp2
    from mytable t
    cross apply (
        values (
            case when level = 1 and type = 'Group' then question end,
            case when level = 2 and type = 'Group' then question end
        ) 
    ) as v(question1, question2)
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're experiencing an overflow in memory due to the self join.  Create a CTE or 2 that removes the rows with null and then join the CTE(s) it to the table instead.  I bet if you looked up your execution plan, you have nested loops and sorts that are killing hour query.  My solution should reduce the impact of those.